# Cartesian products in categories of subobjects

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and $A$ be an object of $\mathcal{C}$. If the inclusion functor from the category $Sub_{\mathcal{C}}(A)$ of subobjects of $A$ (objects are monomorphisms of $\mathcal{C}$ into $A$) into the slice category $\mathcal{C} / A$ has a left adjoint, then (binary) Cartesian products in $Sub_{\mathcal{C}}(A)$ are pullbacks in $\mathcal{C}$.
Are there examples of categories $\mathcal{C}$ with some object $A$ such that (binary) Cartesian products in $Sub_{\mathcal{C}}(A)$ are not pullbacks in $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: If your question is really just the last one: pullbacks are always products in slice categories. But is this really what you are asking? Why are you talking about subobjects when they don't appear in the question?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Thank you for pointing my typo! I meant: in the category of subobjects. I am editing my question.

Comment: Thanks! Now the question is clear to me. It is interesting as well. There will be counterexamples but they will be a bit awkward, since the category cannot have image factorizations as you said. Also, when the pullback exists, it will be the subobject categorical product.

Comment: Are we only talking about binary products?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Yes, my question is about binary Cartesian products. I am adding the word "binary" in the question since it was ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can construct a formal, almost* universal counterexample as follows.

Consider the category generated by the following commutative diagram.

[image: diagram]

Commutativity involves the square in the bottom right and *four* triangles in the top left, and of course everything what follows from it. The two morphisms $U \cap V \rightrightarrows T$ are not equal, though.

In this category, you can prove that

- $\mathrm{Sub}(A)$ has exactly four objects: $A \xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}} A$, $U \to A$, $V \to A$ and $U \cap V \to A$.
- $U \cap V \to A$ is the product of $U \to A$ and $V \to A$ in the category $\mathrm{Sub}(A)$
- $T \to U$ and $T \to V$ are no monomorphisms (this is what the two morphisms $U \cap V \rightrightarrows T$ are for*)
- There is no morphism $T \to U \cap V$. In particular, $U \cap V$ cannot be the pullback of $U \to A$ and $V \to A$.

*First, I thought about introducing another object $B$ with two morphisms $B \rightrightarrows T$ that are equalized by $T \to U$ and $T\to V$, to witness that they are no monomorphisms. But since then no non-identity morphism has codomain $B$, the $B \rightrightarrows A$ will be monomorphisms and we need a morphism $B \to U \cap V$ to ensure that $U \cap V$ is the product. I think we can simplify this by just letting $B = U \cap V$. This makes the example non-universal, but a bit simpler to work with.

Comment: Is there a technical definition of "universal example"?

Comment: Yes, a category with an example in it such that every other example has a unique functor from it that maps the examples to another.